# How to alter the order of these divs?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a column of divs. I'm trying to make it so that when I click a given div, that div replaces the position of the div above or below depending on where the div is. It's better understood if you look at the result -- http://jsfiddle.net/SuperBoi45/vgVnj/

It almost works. Notice how when you click the div at the bottom, it goes up. But when I want to click that div again, it's supposed to go back down. But it doesn't do that. Can you please point out what I can do to make this work. Here is the code for a quick view:

```
<div id="colors">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="yellow"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var colors = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    $('colors').getElementsByTagName('div'));
colors.forEach(function(e, i) {
    colors[i].onclick = function() {
        var a = colors[i + 1],
            b = colors[i - 1],
            _this = this,
            node;
        node = !a ? b : a;
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(node, _this);
    };
});

function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

If I click the top div, it should go down and the one below it should go up where it used to be. If I click one of the two middle divs, it should go up and the one that used to be above it go down. If I click the bottom div, it should go up.

Comment: Can you further explain exactly what the desired behavior is? When should a div go up and when should it go down?

Comment: If I click the top div, it should go down and the one below it should go up where it used to be. If I click one of the two middle divs, it should go up and the one that used to be above it go down. If I click the bottom div, it should go up.

Comment: I just gave you a working solution using moo tools and a little bit of native js which you can replace with the moo tool equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgVnj/1/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("#colors div").click(function(){
        if($(this).next().length > 0){
            $(this).next().after(this);
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().prepend(this);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks but can you please write this over in pure JavaScript. I don't know who added the jquery tag to this post..

Comment: Let me do it for you in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with your numbering of the colours.. here i have updated the solution to work with the numbers in a better way..

http://jsfiddle.net/vgVnj/5/

FYI not familiar with MOO Tools so using native JS methods